# What is std::vector<int> initialised to?

Tags: c++

```
std::vector<int> foo(5);  // creates 5-element int vector
```

what is the value (or that is the values) of foo?
I understand that it creates a 5-element character vector, but what is the value of each, is it zero or undefined?

Comment: You might want to fix the `int`/`char` inconsistency and find a [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector).

Comment: Chris, what do you mean?

Comment: The title creates a vector of ints and then says it's a vector of char. The post does the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

When you use this particular constructor of `std::vector`, the elements of the vector are value initialized.

See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector for more details on `vector::vector`.

See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization for more on value initialization.

For your case, the elements are of type `int`. That implies each of the elements the vector is initialized to zero.